# Ошибка при работе с указателями

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <conio.h>

void main() 
{ 
    int a, *p;

    scanf("%i", a);

    *p = &a;

    printf("%i", p);

    _getch(); 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <conio.h>

void main() 
{ 
    int a = 0;
    int *p = NULL;

    scanf("%i", &a);

    p = &a;

    printf("%p\n", p); 
    printf("%i\n", *p);

    _getch(); 
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, теперь все работает, но почему нельзя написать так: int a, *p = NULL; scanf("%i", &a); p = &a; printf("%i", *p); 
Все переменные и указатели нужно сначала обнулять?

Comment: @Alexandr Так вполне можно написать. Занулять переменные и указатели необязательно.

Comment: Т.е. указатель можно выводить и как переменную, и как её адрес

Comment: @wow Не согласен. В С и С++ есть два понятия: объявление и определение. Если коротко, то после объявления компилятор видит переменные, но под них не выделена память. При определении под переменные выделяется память. Если вы напишете int i; Вы просто объявите переменную. Вы не сможете прочитать ее значения, пока не будет ее определения, тк читать просто нечего. С указателями тоже самое.

Comment: > Если вы напишете int i; Вы просто объявите переменную. Вы не >сможете прочитать ее значения, пока не будет ее определения, тк >читать просто нечего.
Не совсем точное утверждение. Пример:
int i;

// Прочитали значение(мусор). хотя переменная просто объявлена.
int y = i;
 
Если с премеенной никаких действий не происходит - то она просто счи тается не объявлена (или не определена??) и выкенется нормальным вменяемым компилятором из assembler'ного кода. Что такое тогда определение переменной?

Comment: Определение, это когда под переменную выделяется память, собственно присваивается значение.

Answer (score 2):

В чистом виде пример выглядит так:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main() 
{ 
    int a, *p;

    scanf("%i", a);

    *p = &a;

    printf("%i", p);
}
```

Если собрать его с помощью gcc:

```
$ gcc file.c -o file
```

то компилятор выведет сообщение об предупреждениях:

> file.c:8: warning: format `‘%i’` expects type `‘int *’`, but argument 2 has type `‘int’`
> file.c:10: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast
> file.c:12: warning: format `‘%i’` expects type `‘int’`, but argument 2 has type `‘int *’`

В них все и дело. Во первых, функции scanf и printf ожидают другой формат данных, отличный от того, который им подается. Во-вторых, адрес переменной присваивается не указателю, а целому, на которое указатель указывает.